# evaluation of the integral $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\cos(ut)}{\sqrt{x-t}}dt $

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

Can the integral $$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\cos(ut)}{\sqrt{x-t}}dt $$ be expressed in terms of elemental functions or in terms of the sine and cosine integrals ? if possible i would need a hint thanks.

From the fractional calculus i guess this integral is the half derivative of the sine function (i think so)  $ \sqrt \pi \frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}\sin(ux) $ or similar

of course i could expand the cosine into power series  and then take the term by term integration but i would like if possible a closed expression for my integral

Comment: Dear @Jose check if I editted right? :)

Comment: Does it help to use $v = \frac{t}{x}$?

Comment: aha.. yes Babak nice edit

Comment: The title does not correspond to the question.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that. (+1)

Comment: I may suppose it has some connections with Fresnel integrals.

Comment: oh sorry i wanted to write 'evaluation' instead of convergence :D ca someone edit the title ?

Comment: Maple evaluates this in terms of Fresnel integrals.  So I guess it is not elementary.

Comment: Make the right substitution (and trig expansion), and end up with indefinite integrals of $\cos(y)/\sqrt{y}$ and $\sin(y)/\sqrt{y}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=x-y^2$. We then have $dt = -2ydy$. Hence, we get that
\begin{align}
I = \int_0^x \dfrac{\cos(ut)}{\sqrt{x-t}} dt & = \int_0^{\sqrt{x}} \dfrac{\cos(u(x-y^2))}{y} \cdot 2y dy\\
& = 2 \cos(ux) \int_0^{\sqrt{x}}\cos(uy^2)dy + 2 \sin(ux) \int_0^{\sqrt{x}}\sin(uy^2)dy\\
& = \dfrac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{\sqrt{u}} \left(\cos(ux) C\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2ux}{\pi}}\right) + \sin(ux) S\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2ux}{\pi}}\right) \right)
\end{align}
where $C(z)$ and $S(z)$ are the [Fresnel integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).